# Python Parsing JSON With Strange Format

Tags: python, json

I'm not really sure what to call this it might be a fairly standard JSON format but I've not encountered it before.

Simplified example:

```
stock: {
    1223581: {
    shoe_id: 1788,
    id: 123
    }
}
```

My standard would be something like:

```
for item in json_data['stock']:
  print item['shoe_id']
```

But the integer (the 1223581 in this example) is dynamic and it's throwing me.

I've tried:

```
print item[item]['shoe_id']
```

Since `item[item]` was dumping the integer. Also tried:

```
print item[0]['shoe_id']
```

I could parse out anything before the ':' and parse it that way but that seems like an ugly fix to what I imagine would be a straightforward problem.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: use get() method of dictionary and check for None , instead of directly specifying the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the items in your json parsed structure - in `stock`:

```
stock: {
    1223581: {
        shoe_id: 1788,
        id: 123
    }
}

for item_id, item_spec in item['stock'].items()
    print item_spec['shoe_id']
```